# Import Vue breaks Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can someone explain the **WHY** of how `Import Vue from 'vue'` breaks the rendering of the template? I've seen other answers on how to work around this, but none of them have gone into the details of why it breaks.

I ran `npm init` and `npm install vue`, not using the CLI.

I created an `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <first-task></first-task>
        {{msg}}
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and an `app.js` looking like:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'; //Remove to fix

Vue.component('first-task', {
  template: '<p>Hello World!</p>'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      msg: "Hello World"
    }
});
```

Removing the import, it renders fine, but it's unclear to me why this happens. My only guesses are that the default `new Vue` doesn't reference the full build, or that the implicit Render() doesn't get called, but I'm unsure of how to look into this more.

Answer (score 1):

`import` statements may only appear in a javascript *module*

```
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

Should fix it, though you would not need to import `Vue` with your current code anyway, as you have seen